# blurred image inside text // CSS HTML

Tags: html, css, image, filter, sass

I would like to blur the image inside the text.
but as soon as i add the blur filter the text blurs too.

The solution it probably dead simple.
But i'm stuck with this one for quite some time now.
Any help is appreciated.

How I would like it to look:

[image: img1]

How it looks so far:

[image: img2]

```css
body {
  background: #16171a;
}

.bg {
  background-image: url(https://xl.movieposterdb.com/21_08/2021/1160419/xl_1160419_230b1df1.jpg?v=2021-10-28%2022:02:33);
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(10%);
          filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(10%);
}

.title {
  background-image: url(https://xl.movieposterdb.com/21_08/2021/1160419/xl_1160419_230b1df1.jpg?v=2021-10-28%2022:02:33);
  background-size: cover;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 40vw;
  font-family: 'Teko';
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-filter: saturate(90) blur(20px);
          filter: saturate(90) blur(20px);
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Teko:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="title">DUNE</div>
    <div class="bg"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please could you make your code into a working snippet - that will mean having to include your image as well because at the moment it shows nothing. Thanks. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry for that. First post. Hope it works now.

Comment: Thanks - I can see the background through the letters now, but nothing is blurred (I'm on Edge/Windows10).

Comment: what about now?

Comment: Yes! Have got blurriness.

Comment: getting there, thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

You could just blur the source-image itself? Download the image you have now and blur it on https://www.befunky.com/create/blur-image/ for example.

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The solution i ended up with was to use a SVG element with a TEXT element inside

```css
#bg{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position-y: center;
  z-index: 90;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(10%);
}

#text{ 
  font-family: 'Teko';
  font-size: 40vw;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: fixed; left:0; top:0;
  z-index: 100;
}

#text rect{
  color: white;
  fill: none
}


#movieImage{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: saturate(100) blur(50px); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Teko:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <svg id="text" height="100%" width="100%">
        <defs>
            <mask id="mask" x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%">
                <rect x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%"/>
                <text id="title" x="50%" y="60%" fill="white" text-anchor="middle" >DUNE</text>
            </mask>
        </defs>
        <image id ="movieImage" xlink:href="https://xl.movieposterdb.com/21_08/2021/1160419/xl_1160419_230b1df1.jpg?v=2021-10-28%2022:02:33" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" mask="url(#mask)" /> 
        <rect x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%"/>
    </svg>
    <div id="bg" style="background-image: url('https://xl.movieposterdb.com/21_08/2021/1160419/xl_1160419_230b1df1.jpg?v=2021-10-28%2022:02:33')"></div>
</body>
</html>

<!-- width="100%" height="100%"  -->
```